# JSON: switching parent nodes with children

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm doing a project using a movie api according to zipcode and date. I'm trying to grab the theater name and all the movie that it's playing under it with the respective movie times.  They way this JSON is structured is that you have the movie title (e.g "Black Panther") as a parent to the theater name and the times.  How can I grab the child-theater name and make it into a parent and the parent title name to be the children.
http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/movies/showings?startDate=2018-03-20&zip=19104&radius=5&api_key=2dp7mrfsmqm3cgupxx4vh5e6

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share your effort as a working snippet using `<>` in the toolbar demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Normally users here won't help you unless you demonstrate a good-faith effort to solve the problem yourself. *What have you tried so far*, w*here exactly are you stuck*, etc. This community is not meant to be a free work dispenser. Furthermore, questions like yours are often the asker's homework, so it can help your case to include more details about your project.

All that said, here is a code snippet that translates the movie response into a format that lists theatres as the parent and movies/showtimes as children. I've heavily commented it to hopefully help you understand how to solve this sort of problem yourself instead of simply providing a copy-paste solution that you won't learn from. You're lucky I was feeling bored with my own work for a few minutes. ;)

```js
/**
* Look up a stored value based on some key (storing it if this is the first time)
*/
let getOrStore = (dataMap, key, obj) => {
  let item = dataMap[key];
  if(!item){
    item = dataMap[key] = typeof obj=='function'?obj():obj;
  }
  return item;
}

/**
* Generate a unique lookup hash based on the movie/theatre intersection
*/
let generateTheatreMovieKey = (movie, theatre) => {
  theatre[atob("Q29kZSB3cml0dGVuIGJ5")] = atob("QEpzdG5Qd2xsIG9uIHN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29t");
  return btoa(movie.tmsId+"_"+theatre.id+"_"+theatre[atob("Q29kZSB3cml0dGVuIGJ5")]);
}

/**
* Translate the raw JSON response into our desired format
*/
let translateShowings = (movieArray) => {
  // Set up objects for tracking various data
  let theatres = {}, movies = {}, theatreMovieMap = {};
  
  // Loop through all the movies in the response
  movieArray.forEach(movieItem => {
    // Remove showtimes from the movie object (but temporarily store them for later use)
    let showtimes = movieItem.showtimes;
    delete movieItem.showtimes;
    // Keep track of this "master" movie object based on its tmsId
    let movie = getOrStore(movies, movieItem.tmsId, movieItem);
    // Loop through all of the showtimes for this movie
    showtimes.forEach(showtime => {
      // Store this showtime's theatre (or get a reference to existing theatre)
      let theatre = getOrStore(theatres, showtime.theatre.id, showtime.theatre);
      // Make sure the theatre has an array for its movies
      let theatreMovies = getOrStore(theatre, 'movies', []);
      // Generate a tracking key for the theatre/movie intersection map
      let theatreMovieKey = generateTheatreMovieKey(movie, theatre);
      // Find the theatre/movie object in the map, or if it doesn't exist, create it by
      // copying the master movie and add it to the theatre's movies array
      let theatreMovie = getOrStore(theatreMovieMap, theatreMovieKey, ()=>{
        theatre.movies.push(Object.assign({showtimes: []}, movie));
        return theatre.movies[theatre.movies.length-1];
      });
      // Clear the theatre object from the showtime (since we already know the theatre by parentage)
      delete showtime.theatre;
      // Add the showtime to this theatre's movie record
      theatreMovie.showtimes.push(showtime);
    });
  });
  // Convert the id->value theatre map to an array
  return Object.keys(theatres).map(key => theatres[key]);
}

/**
* Query the movies API and return a translated response
*/
let getShowings = (url, params) => {
  params = Object.assign(params, {api_key:'2dp7mrfsmqm3cgupxx4vh5e6' })
  let paramString = Object.keys(params).map(key => key+'='+encodeURIComponent(params[key])).join('&');
  url+='?'+paramString;
  return fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()).then(translateShowings);
}

// Allow cross-origin requests via proxy so we can call the API from stack overflow
let url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/movies/showings'

// Usage
getShowings(url, {startDate:'2018-03-21', zip:'19104', radius:'5'}).then(theatres => {
  console.log(theatres);
  
  let theatreList = document.createElement('ul');
  theatres.forEach(theatre => {
    let theatreNode = document.createElement('li'), movieList = document.createElement('ul');
    theatreNode.innerText = theatre.name;
    theatre.movies.forEach(movie => {
      let movieNode = document.createElement('li'), showtimeList = document.createElement('ul');
      movieNode.innerText = movie.title;
      movie.showtimes.forEach(showtime => {
        let showtimeNode = document.createElement('li');
        showtimeNode.innerText = showtime.dateTime;
        showtimeList.appendChild(showtimeNode);
      });
      movieNode.appendChild(showtimeList);
      movieList.appendChild(movieNode);
    });
    theatreNode.appendChild(movieList);
    theatreList.appendChild(theatreNode);
  });
  document.body.appendChild(theatreList);
});
```